# How to get the whole form as a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to build my own form builder using javascript and php,
I have a problem getting the whole form as I want to display the same form on the other page.
I want to generate a string which contain whole form link. After clicking that link same form will be generated

The javascript code is

```
 $('document').ready(function(){
            var flag=0;
            $(".divname").draggable({
                helper : "clone"
            });

            $( ".drop_class" ).droppable({

                drop: function( event, ui ) {

                    switch(ui.helper.context.id){
                        case "heading_id":
                            $( this ).append( "<div class='default_css' id='header'>Write Heading Here<input id='head_id' name='hello' class='common' type='text'/></div>" );
                            break;
                        case "textbox_id":
                            $( this ).append( "<div class='default_css'>Write Text Here<input id='text_id' class='common'type='text'/></br></div>" );
                            break;
                        case "textarea_id":
                            $( this ).append( "<div class='default_css'>Enter Information<textarea id='tarea_id' class='common'rows=5 cols=70></textarea></div>" );
                            break;    
                        case "radio_id":
                            $( this ).append( "<div class='default_css'>Gender</br><input type='radio' value='male' name='sex'>Male<br><input type='radio' value='female' name='sex'>Female" );
                            break;
                        case "fullname_id":
                            $( this ).append( "<div class='default_css'>First Name<input id='fname_id' class='common' type='text'/>Last Name<input type='text'id='lname_id'/></br></div>" );
                            break;
                        case "mobile_id":
                            $( this ).append( "<div class='default_css'>Enter Mobile Number<input id='mob_id' class='common' type='text'/></div>");
                            break;   
                        }
                        if(flag==0){
                            $( this ).append("<div class='default_css'><input type='button' id='submit_button' style='position:absolute;right:330px;bottom:0;'value='submit'/></div><div id='generate_id'><input type='button' style='position:absolute;right:100px;bottom:0;' value='Generate URL'/>");
                        }
                        flag = 1;   
                    }    
                });


            });
```

How do I get whole form

Comment: Would _$formHTML = $("#idOfForm").html();_ work for you?

Answer (score 3):

Consider

```
$formHTML = $("#idOfForm").html();
```

Comment: I want whole form as it is including inputs given by user as in form builder

Comment: Before using this answer, you've to set all values of attributes in your `form` corresponding to the choises user has done, then you'll get the string you want.

Comment: @sarthi this code will give you the raw HTML for the form. You can send this to the next page and using server side code just display it as-is,  between `<form>` tags.

Comment: I got form html now how to get a string from html scripts

Comment: Please tell me how to get a string of  html

Comment: what do you mean?  what are you trying?  Are you using .html() on a jQuery element that represents a DOM element?